# iptables bridge redirect is also redirecting other interfaces

Tags: iptables, bridge

Running a Ubuntu 14.04LTS home server machine.  I have small IOT device that sends HTTP posts to a remote web server that I want to redirect to a local process (basically intercept it's posts to my own local process).  The server is using eth0 (builtin ethernet port), the IOT device is on eth1 which is a USB ethernet dongle.  I've created a bridge in /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet dhcp 
auto eth1 
iface eth1 inet manual 
auto br0 
iface br0 inet dhcp    
   bridge_ports eth0 eth1
```

I used the following iptables rule to redirect the bridge traffic to local port 22041.  That works fine.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i br0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22041
```

The problem is that it also seems to be redirecting port 80 traffic to the server when anything on the LAN attempts to access a web page.  If I run 'firefox http://127.0.0.1/page' from the server, it works fine.  If I run 'firefox httpt://server_ip/page' from another machine on the LAN, it gets redirected to port 22041.

I thought that the '-i br0' would only apply this rule to traffic coming from the bridge but obviously that's not what's going on.  How do I stop iptables from redirecting outside traffic to port 22041?

Thanks in advance,
TD

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found my own answer in another post.  If I use physdev to match eth1 instead of matching on the bridge, it appears to work and doesn't stop my regular traffic.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -m physdev --physdev-in eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 22041
```